# MongoDB connection timed out

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I have a MongoDB database on a web server. I have made a connection in Laravel from another server, using this: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. It works, until yesterday!

If I try to connect now, I have an error: Failed to connect to: "host":27017: Connection timed out. I tried it from another server, I got the same problem. But, if I try to connect from my local computer with Robomongo, it works!

From my web server, I can connect to other MongoDB databases and it works fine, but I can not connect to the database I want to connect.

I tried with Laravel, and I have set up another PHP MongoClient script, but it does not work either.

Comment: The answer is very simple: FIREWALL :)

Comment: try to telnet to it: ```telnet %host% 27017```